# NPN Transistors

Tags: transistors, npn, pn-junction

How does NPN transistors actually work? In the picture below, I understand that electrons flow in A as the n-p junction of the Emitter and Base is forward-biased. However, the p-n junction of Base and Collector is reverse-biased, so how does the electrons in B flow?

[image]

Comment: Do some youtube search, there are some people that explain it quite ok there, as it works best with some images.

Comment: A very simplistic view on this: The E-B junction is in forward, the B region is very narrow/short. So electrons that happily cross the E-B junction get too close to the collector and are sucked into it (the collector). As I said, this is a simplistic view, not scientific in any way but maybe helps you to understand. Dave Jones is the man you need to see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUeK7pHe0rI
Just watch that video (and all his other videos as well) and become a 1st rate engineer :-)

Comment: Such questions that can easily be answered with a Google search are closed.

Comment: If you really want to know how it works, I suggest starting with a good book on Solid-State physics. I used Kittel, which dates back more than 50 years. If you just want to design circuits, you should study the characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

**Very short (and incomplete) explanation:**
There are many things to understand first but I think the most important thing is to know that currents can be differentiated by their cause:
**Drift** current is caused by a gradient of the electrical field (voltage).
**Diffusion** current is caused by a gradient of concentration of carriers (i.e. electrons or holes).

Minority carriers (electrons in the p-region) reach the collector by diffusion (→ diffusion current).
It requires the base to be thin enough that only a small percentage of 
minority carriers are lost by recombination (i.e. thickness of base << diffusion length; that's why it doesn't work with two discrete diodes connected back to back).

To understand the whole process I suggest to understand drift and diffusion current, minority carriers, diffusion length, recombination, pn-junction, ...

Answer (score 0):

**In short:**

- B-E junction is forward biased and causes electrons (better: negative charges) to move from the emitter (it "emittes") to the base region (forward biased pn junction) which is very thin.
- Therefore, the majority of the carriers has enough energy to cross this depletion area and will be "collected" by the collector potential which is larger than the base potential (that means: The C-B junction is reverse biased). This is the collector current.
- A (small) rest of the charged carriers forms the base current.
- Therefore: The B-E voltage causes the emitter current IE which is split into the collector current IC and the (small) base current IB: IE=IC+IB.
- That means: The voltage VBE controls/determines both currents: IC and IB. And the ratio IC/IB is nearly constant (called "current gain").